# Sending new String value to another class not working? (Works only first time)

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, final, yahoo-api

I am using Google's FusedLocationAPI and YahooAPI to get my current location(From fusedlocationAPI) and send it to yahooAPI and get the weather for my location.

In the onCreate method, I get the weather from yahooCom.refresh(slocation) method. But however, I want to get the weather everytime onlocationUpdates() method is called. But When I try to do that, it doesnt get the weather anymore.

So basically, The first value of the slocation String I send to the YahooCom class works, but when I change the variable value and send it again, it does not work (not updating weather)

How do I do to get the weather update when location updates? I am a beginner android coder, so please excuse my question if it's dumb.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, YahooComCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //here I am finding all views by id etc etc...

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_FASTEST);
    locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); 

    yahooCom = new YahooCom(this);
    //yahooCom.refresh(slocation); works here the first time
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    requestLocationUpdates();
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FINE_LOCATION);

        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLatitude));
    longitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLongitude));
    slocation = ""+Double.toString(mLatitude)+","+Double.toString(mLongitude)+"";
    yahooCom.refresh(slocation);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(googleApiClient.isConnected())
        requestLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,this);
}

@Override
public void serviceSuccess(Channel channel) {

    code.setText("Code: "+Integer.toString(channel.getItem().getCondition().getCode()));
    city.setText(channel.getLocation().getCity());
    temperature.setText(Integer.toString(channel.getItem().getCondition().getTemperature())+" \u00B0 C");
    condition.setText(channel.getItem().getCondition().getDescription());

}
```

}

**EDIT:**

Here is the code from the refresh() method from YahooCom class:

```
public void refresh(final String location){
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            yql = String.format("select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"%s\") and u=\"C\"", slocation);
            endPoint = String.format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json", Uri.encode(yql));

            try {

                URL url = new URL(endPoint);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    result.append(line);
                }
                return result.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                exception = e;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            if(s == null && exception != null){
                yahooComCallback.serviceFailure(exception);
                return;
            }
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(s);

                JSONObject query = data.optJSONObject("query");
                int count = query.optInt("count");
                if(count == 0){
                    yahooComCallback.serviceFailure(new LocationException("Location does not exist, or no weather information was found for this location"));
                    return;
                }

                Channel channel = new Channel();
                channel.populate(query.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel"));
                yahooComCallback.serviceSuccess(channel);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                yahooComCallback.serviceFailure(e);
            }

        }
    }.execute(location);

}
```

Comment: are you sure you are not hitting an API limit? refreshing the weather every time a location changes seems pretty extreme, weather does not change that much that you should need to get an update every time a location changes

Comment: @tyczj how do I know I'm hitting the limit? Btw I am not using an API key for this at all.

Comment: the result from your call to yahoo should provide some indication as to if you hit a limit or not. Just because you dont use an api key does not mean you cant get limited in some way

Comment: @tyczj how do I find that out? I read on their website that its limited to 2000 requests/day for each API. Can I add my API key anywhere in my app?

Comment: @tyczj sorry but the information was wrong in my last comment. It's actually limited at 2000 requests/hour per IP-adress without an API key. So there is no limitation problems here, It must be a app problem I think. Please can you look at my refresh() method in YahooCom class, and see if you find anything that might be the problem?